How to use leftjoin with subquery in QueryDSL?
I want to make followers list in Spring,
It works at mysql but I can't use left join with subquery.
How do I use left join with subquery in QueryDSL(I used by QueryDSL 5.0.0)?
-- original sql
select f.id, u.id as user_id, u.nickname,
    case
        when f.from_user_id = 19 then 0 # my
        when my.to_user_id is null then 1 # not follow
        else 2 # follow
    end as is_follow
from follow f
left join user u
on f.from_user_id = u.id
left join (select distinct m.to_user_id, m.from_user_id
           from follow m
           where m.from_user_id = 19) as my
on f.from_user_id = my.to_user_id
where f.to_user_id = 1
order by f.id desc
limit 10;

